# Mysql select and use in php

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I am trying to figure this out, I want to call several rows say in the range of 5 - 40 from mysql. I then would like to take the four variables in each row and use them in php in a foreach statement.

I was hoping someone might be bale to give me a hand. This is the code I am working with right now.

```
include ('php/opendb.php');

$frontad_mysql = mysql_query("SELECT title, city, ad_image, rent FROM rentals WHERE front_page_ad = '1' AND paid = '1' ") or die(mysql_error());
$front_ads = array();
    while($front_ads = mysql_fetch_assoc($frontad_mysql)) {
    $front_ads[] = $row;
    }

$ads = "<div id='ad_container'>";

$x = 0;
foreach ($front_ad as $fa){
$ads .= "<div id='$x' class='front_ads'>".$fa['$x']['title']."<br/><img src='".$fa['$x']['ad_image']."' class='frontad_image' /><br/>".$fa['$x']['city']."<br/>Price: $".$fa['$x']['rent']."</div>";
}

$ads .= "</div>";

mysql_close();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using

```
$fa['$x']
```

Single quotes doesn't <strike>replace</strike> expand variables .. it takes everything literally. Change it into

```
$fa["$x"]
```

or

```
$fa[$x]
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: Ok wasn't thinking it would be that simple I thought I was totally off base with my structure of the variable, but I will give this a try and see if it works. Thanks for the quick response =)

Comment: Ok awsome got it working. The only other thing I had to do was change $fa[$x] over to $front_ads[$x]   -   I appreciate the help - Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this:

```
while($front_ads = mysql_fetch_assoc($frontad_mysql)) {
    $front_ads[] = $row;
}
```

Be more like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($frontad_mysql)) {
    $front_ads[] = $row;
}
```

The first one is just pulling some data out of the database, trying to append `$row` onto it, and then throwing it all away. That's probably not what you want to do.

Comment: Whoo .. missed that one! Nice catch ;)

Comment: Ah, right on I dont know how I missed that. The one other thing is I think the syntax is wrong within the foreach loop. I have tried variations but it is not getting the variables. 'code'$fa['$x']['title']'code' is the $x correct to be using to grabbing different keys.

Comment: @Tianbo84: micha has you covered on that one.

Comment: @Tianbo84: You're using `mysql_fetch_assoc` and setting `$x` to `0`, so probably not. Use `mysql_fetch_array` instead ..

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve first your objective of getting only ranged record can be completed by LIMIT ..like this

```
SELECT title, city, ad_image, rent FROM rentals WHERE front_page_ad = '1' AND paid = '1' LIMIT 5,35
```

it will only bring 5-40 data ..

Comment: Sorry getting the rows between 5 and 40 was more so an example of how many I was pulling at a time. My objective is I want to set each variable in the foreach loop. Like image[1] image[2] image[3] and so on and same with the other variables of city, rent, and title. Thanks